# TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float Image data cannot be converted to float

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib

As I trying to work on python with the open `cv` and the `flask` module to remove the background color from an image. As running the code, I am getting this error:

```
File "new.py", line 82, in <module>
    plt.imshow(None)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2699, in imshow
    None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1810, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5494, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 634, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")
TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float
```

I am not getting how to resolve this issue.And the code which i m working :

```
import io, traceback

from flask import Flask, request, g
from flask import send_file
from flask_mako import MakoTemplates, render_template
from plim import preprocessor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ExifTags
from scipy.misc import imresize
import numpy as np
import cv2
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
# For Plim templates
mako = MakoTemplates(app)
app.config['MAKO_PREPROCESSOR'] = preprocessor
app.config.from_object('config')
image= cv2.imread("1.jpg")
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

def ml_predict(image):
    with graph.as_default():
       # Add a dimension for the batch
       prediction = img.predict(image[None, :, :, :])
       prediction = prediction.reshape((224,224, -1))
       return prediction

def rotate_by_exif(image):
    try:
       for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys() :
           if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation]=='Orientation' : break
           exif=dict(image._getexif().items())
           if not orientation in exif:
               return image

           if exif[orientation] == 3 :
               image=image.rotate(180, expand=True)
           elif exif[orientation] == 6 :
               image=image.rotate(270, expand=True)
           elif exif[orientation] == 8 :
               image=image.rotate(90, expand=True)
           return image
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return image

THRESHOLD = 0.5

def predict():
    # Load image
    #image = request.files['file']
    image = Image.open(image)
    image = rotate_by_exif(image)
    resized_image = imresize(image, (224, 224)) / 255.0
    # Model input shape = (224,224,3)
    # [0:3] - Take only the first 3 RGB channels and drop ALPHA 4th channel in case this is a PNG
    prediction = ml_predict(resized_image[:, :, 0:3])
    print('PREDICTION COUNT', (prediction[:, :, 1]>0.5).sum())

    # Resize back to original image size
    # [:, :, 1] = Take predicted class 1 - currently in our model = Person class. Class 0 = Background
    prediction = imresize(prediction[:, :, 1], (image.height, image.width))
    prediction[prediction>THRESHOLD*255] = 255
    prediction[prediction<THRESHOLD*255] = 0

    # Append transparency 4th channel to the 3 RGB image channels.
    transparent_image = np.append(np.array(image)[:, :, 0:3], prediction[: , :, None], axis=-1)
    transparent_image = Image.fromarray(transparent_image)



plt.imshow(None)
plt.show()
```

Any Help regarding this is really appreciated. And in Advance Thank you so much for helping to resolve this issue.

Comment: maybe you meant `plt.imshow(transparent_image`)?

Comment: @xbound  i have tried using the transparent image but then also the error is being occured. and the error is:                                                                
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 79, in <module>
    plt.imshow(transparent_image)
NameError: name 'transparent_image' is not defined

Comment: Do you get different error?

Comment: @Justice_Lords even plt.imshow(Image)  doesnot work.

Comment: i have edited the previous message box. please have a look. Thanks

Comment: well, current error is because you're trying to pass `None` object to `plt.imshow` although error itself looks weird should show something like `NoneType has no ...`. You must better explain what you're trying to achive in your question.

Comment: @xbound  My work is to remove the background from an image with a white color. So, i have tried writing this code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `plt.imshow(transparent_image)` inside the `predict` function.

It complained that `transparent_image` is not defined because you tried to use that local variable of `predict` function outside of its scope.

Comment: I have tried but again, i have got a new error :                     
            "IndentationError: expected an indented block"                                                                              if you could say me with respect to the code what changes can be done to get the specific output.    Anyways  , Thanks for your reply

Comment: Show me how the code looks like after the change. Put the lines with imshow and show directly after the last row of predict function and it should work.

Comment: please have a look to the piece of code:
# Append transparency 4th channel to the 3 RGB image channels.
transparent_image = np.append(np.array(image)[:, :, 0:3], prediction[: , :, None], axis=-1)
transparent_image = Image.fromarray(transparent_image)
plt.imshow('transparent_image')
plt.imshow()

Comment: You need to pass the variable with image you want to show to the imshow function.
`plt.imshow('transparent_image')` is wring because you pass string here, not image.
`plt.imshow()` is wrong because you don't pass any argument at all here. 
You need to call `plt.imshow(transparent_image)`

Also, your last error was about indentation, and if you paste your code without newlines I won't be able to tell what's wrong with the indentation.

Comment: Many more thanks for your reply. Regarding indentations, I have hopefully cleared the error. As you said to add 'plt.imshow(transparent_image)' . I tried using this also it got executed but i am not getting the expected o/p . The output i am getting is:                                                                                          : FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 329
  ''', re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)
Using TensorFlow backend.
Loading model